# Starting a forever process in a Jenkins build step?

Tags: deployment, node.js, jenkins

I'm running a shell command at the end of a Jenkins deployment to restart a forever script:

```
npm install && forever stop app.js && forever start -a -l /var/log/forever.log app.js
```

When I run that as a user jenkins everything works fine and the console output from the build history also tells me that the forever script is running. However, the process stops right after the deployment is finished and the forever process is stopped.

What causes this behavior and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Jenkins kills all process spawn by the job.

This can be disabled by setting the `BUILD_ID` environment variable to something else:

```
export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
```

see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller for details

Comment: Is this a 'clean' way to do or something else recommended?

Comment: As far as I know, it's the only way to disable the ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: rcomblen is correct, check out https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: Before this I was getting. [ssh-agent] Stopped.
Killed by signal 15.
Killed by signal 15.
After this I got [ssh-agent] Stopped. But it is still being killed :(

Comment: The link is dead now. The only reference I found so far is https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/extensions/jenkins-core/#processkiller.

Comment: This is the current documentation:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/spawning-processes/

Answer (score 3):

In the new Pipeline jobs, setting `BUILD_ID` no longer works.  Instead, you need to set `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE` to prevent Jenkins from killing your process when the job finishes.

```
sh 'export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe'
sh 'myProcess'
```

Or, more selectively:

```
sh 'JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe myProcess'
```

See [the wiki on ProcessTreeKiller](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller) and [this comment in the Jenkins Jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28182?focusedCommentId=304426&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-304426).

Comment: Isn't each `sh` step its own shell? I don't think the export in your first shell is going to exist in the second shell.

Answer (score 2):

The question is quite old, but there is a better solution in this case I think.

Use [Post-Build Script Plug-In](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin)

The plugin itself is not updated since the beginning of 2016, but it does the job and you do not have to fiddle with environment variables. Seems a bit neater to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
(
  set -e
  export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe
  export JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontKillMe
  npm install
  forever stop app.js
  forever start -a -l /var/log/forever.log app.js &
) &
```